# Good way to start programming for PixelSense

Tags: pixelsense

I'd like to start to program for Microsoft Surface 1.0. Do you have any recommendations for good introductions in this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this pdf file to start with -

http://www.cs.uml.edu/~holly/teaching/91550/fall2009/handouts/lab2/XNA%20Quick%20Start.pdf

Comment: Do you also know a good site for tutorials or something like this?